# Share Facebook accessToken between frontend (Angular2) and backend (Spring Boot)

Tags: javascript, facebook, spring-boot, spring-social, spring-social-facebook

I have an Angular2 app that uses the Web Facebook SDK to obtain an accessToken.

```
FB.login((result:any) => {
  console.log(result.authResponse.accessToken)
  this.getUser();
}, {scope: 'user_friends'});
```

After I retrieve the token, I would like to use it in order to authenticate this user on the backend too. The backend is a simple Spring Boot app with security. However, the flows I've seen so far involving Spring end up using the "response_type=code".

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=****&redirect_uri=http://localhost:9000/login/facebook&response_type=code&state=****
```

I was wondering if there's a way to exchange the accessToken and the code or better yet, a best practice for this kind of situations.

Thanks,
David

Comment: If you already have an access token, then it makes no sense to perform the step that exchanges a code (which you don't have) for an access token. I don't know if spring is prepared to skip this step and inject an access token from outside, go check the docs on that. If it isn't, you might need to manipulate the code.

Comment: spring social facebook:
Facebook facebook = FacebookTemplate(accessToken);